# Ember versus Angular.JS whilst rendering large table - Performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js

I am going to build a large table with a lot of data (about 2000 elements `<td>`). I would like to have some functions to calculate values based on model but I not going to have any bindings there. Mainly I am going just to display data returned in json. Is angular going to render DOM faster than ember in this peculiar case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most tests, Ember.js performs several times slower than AngularJS.

In this testing senario, both frameworks go head to head manipulating data sets of 10,000 elements. Afterwards, they both are called upon to animate 400 objects.

**Rendering** (10,000 elements):
*Ember* - http://jsbin.com/AzaceNo/1/
*Angular* - http://jsbin.com/ucopUca/1/
Result: Angular wins by roughly 400%. This is probably because AngularJS does not set an observer for every element while EmberJS does.

**Data Binding** (Change 10,000 elements):
*Ember* - http://jsbin.com/IYAdIVEP/2/
*Angular* - http://jsbin.com/AGIJUmOj/1/
Result: Ember hangs initially, but renders slightly faster due to observers on each element.

**Operations** (Animate 400 objects):
*Ember* - http://jsbin.com/UCuJiH/1/
*Angular* - http://jsbin.com/uTuqOsO/1/
Result: AngularJS performs much more efficiently and produces a faster, more consistent output because it changes the view right after the $apply() function is called and changes all 400 elements. Ember changes the 400 elements with help from observers, equivalent to calling $apply() 400 times.

Prediction: AngularJS will most likely render your DOM elements for a 2000 element list faster than EmberJS based on previous performance testing involving manipulation of data sets between 400 and 10,000 elements.

Source: voidcanvas

Comment: It's worth pointing out that all the Ember.js examples use an old version of Ember that was released in 2013.  There have been a lot of performance improvements made since then.

Comment: HTMLBars guys... just saying..

Comment: We even don't know when HTMLBars will go out.

Answer (score 1):

Not a really great question (too much opinion). In general:

- Are you planning on using ember-data or something else? Ember-data is pretty rad, but does add some overhead to load/render times. In general ember can be a bit slower, but a lot of the benchmarks I've seen are just that - benchmarks, not real-world performance, and not really something I'd base a huge design decision on.
- Are you a good programmer? When dealing with bigger numbers, it's easy for sloppy programming to be waaaay more significant to performance than the framework itself.
- Are you binding this once and not modifying it? There are tools in angular for binding the data once and not leaving watches behind. I'm not sure if ember works the same way.

If you are binding this once and walking away *and* if performance is such a hog, consider using the server to render the table.

If this is for a big-deal system and you're making a big decision about which framework to use, consider just implementing test cases in both platforms. You'll pretty quickly see the difference between ember and angular in how they work, and you may find that you strongly prefer one modality over another anyway. And you'll have more realistic data.